# Ask confirmation before route change Sveltekit

Tags: javascript, typescript, routes, sveltekit

I want to ask the user confirmation using the `confirm()` function.

For now I track when the user is changing the route with this code:

```
import { navigating } from '$app/stores';

$: if($navigating) alert('changing route');
```

But it changes the route at the same time it's alerting the message. So I don't know how to avoid the route change while the user did not click okay in the `confirm()`

Comment: Have a look at https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-navigation-beforenavigate ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for these answers, it's perfect !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I made it work:

```
beforeNavigate(({from, to, cancel}) => {
    if(!confirm('Leave without saving ?')) {
      cancel();
    }
});
```